# Where can I report a bug for apps.ubuntu.com?

Tags: community, bug-reporting, ubuntu-website

I have a few bugs which I would like to patch for apps.ubuntu.com; however, I can't seem to find their project page on LaunchPad. Where can I get in touch with this team and where can I pull the code from?

Comment: Its interesting that [a google search for "apps.ubuntu.com"](http://www.google.co.in/#q=%22apps.ubuntu.com%22) has this page in top results

Comment: @Capt.Nemo Stack Exchange takes SEO very seriously :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Ubuntu web catalog](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-webcatalog)

Found it by searching google for `"apps.ubuntu.com" site:launchpad.net -oneconf` which shows bugs for `apps.ubuntu.com` in [Ubuntu Web Catalog](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-webcatalog).